# woocommerce checkout scroll to empty field

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, error-handling, hook-woocommerce

On the checkout page when I leave an empty field my page scroll to the top but I want it to scroll on the empty field. can anyone suggest any plugins or hooks for it?